# Joining to a subclass of a Table per Class hierarchy in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, joined-subclass

I'm using the table per subclass mapping inheritance in NHibernate.  I have a parent `Attribute` table and a child `AccountAttribute` table.  The child `AccountAttribute` table has another foreign key in it to a `CustomerProfile` table.  The `CustomerProfile` table has a zero or more relationship to the `AccountAttribute` table; meaning I'll have a collection of `AccountAttributes` in my `CustomerProfile` class.

How do I map the `CustomerProfile` table to the `AccountAttribute` table in my NHibernate mapping so that the `CustomerProfile` class is hydrated with it's correct `AccountAttributes`?

**Tables**

**Attribute:** Attribute_Id (PK)

**AccountAttribute:**
AccountAttribute_Id (PK); 
Attribute_Id (FK); 
CustomerProfile_Id (FK)

**CustomerProfile:**
CustomerProfile_Id (PK)

Mapping for the Attribute/AccountAttribute hierarchy.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" >
  <class name="Attribute, CustomerProfile" lazy="false">

    <id name="Identifier" column="Attribute_Id" access="field.camelcase">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <joined-subclass name="AccountAttribute, CustomerProfile" table="AccountAttribute" lazy="false">
      <key column="Attribute_Id" />
      <property name="ValueText" column="Value_Txt" access="nosetter.camelcase" />
    </joined-subclass>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Mapping for the Account object

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" >
  <class name="Account, CustomerProfile" lazy="false">

    <id name="Identifier" column="Account_Id" access="field.camelcase">
      <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <!-- How do I map to the AccountAttributes table here to get the correct set? -->
    <bag name="AccountAttributes" access="field.camelcase" table="AccountAttribute">
      <key column="Account_Id" />
      <one-to-many class="AccountAttribute, CustomerProfile"/>
    </bag>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Thanks,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is due to the fact that you have given your subclass its own primary key in the table, i.e. `AccountAttribute_id` in `AccountAttribute`.

As you said that you are using *table-per-subclass* all of your subclass tables should use the superclass primary key, therefore the `AccountAttribute` table should only have `Attribute_id` as a primary key which is also a foreign key back to the `Attribute` table.

Once you've made these changes your mapping should then work because it is using the correct `<key />`

---

Refs:

- http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/inheritance.html#inheritance-tablepersubclass
- http://codebetter.com/iancooper/2009/01/21/introduction-to-nhibernate-pt-4/
- http://ang3lfir3.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/table-per-subclass-inheritance-mapping-with-fluent-nhibernate/

Comment: I agree there should be only one primary key - unfortunately there are several things working against me here.  #1 There is a field in the AccountAttribute table that will be updateable - thus the primary key is required.  #2 The relationship between CustomerProfile & AccountAttribute is required as this is a way of dynamically adding attributes (i.e. city, state, zip, etc.) to the CustomerProfile without having to change the database schema.  The more I think about it, the more I think inheritance is not the right way to approach this mapping.